# Convert Common to and from XML

Tags: xml, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

In AX2009, it is possible to convert a record to XML with the following:

```
SalesTable salesTable;
salesTable.xml();
```

Is there also a method somewhere to convert the xml string to a record?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no build-in method to convert an XML string to a record.

Record fields can be assigned from a container, though, like this using CustGroup as an example:

```
public initFromCon(container con)
{
    [this.CustGroup, this.Name] = con;
}
```

What remains for you is to extract the field data from the XML then convert to a container.

```
static void XML2ConTest(Args _args)
{
    str xml = @"<STUDENT>
                 <NUMBER>001</NUMBER>
                 <NAME>Stud_A</NAME> 
                 <CLASS>8</CLASS>
              </STUDENT>";
    XMLDocument xmlDocument = XmlDocument::newXml(xml);
    XMLNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.selectNodes('STUDENT/*');

    container xml2con(XmlNodeList list)
    {
        XMLNodeListIterator it = new XMLNodeListIterator(list);
        XmlNode node;
        container ret;
        while (it.moreValues())
        {
            node = it.value();
            ret += node.text();
            it.nextValue();
        }
        return ret;
    }
    ;
    info(con2Str(xml2con(nodeList)));
}
```

While `xml2con` returns a container of strings, AX will attempt conversion to the target type in a container assignment:

```
int a;
[a] = ['123'];
```

This will work!

Which means you can do this without too much worry:

```
custGroup.initFromCon(xml2con(nodeList));
```

You will of cause be responsible to maintain database integrity, so be sure to call `validateField` for each relevant field and `validateWrite` before doing an `insert`.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it looks like you're tossing the xml node name away completely. Since containers are numeric based (as opposed to a dictionary/string), that means that the resulting container, and by extension the XML document nodes, need to be in a specific order every time with no nodes skipped, right? Or am I missing something? If I'm not, I would think a Map type would be a more appropriate intermediary object.

Comment: You are right, only the element text is saved in the container, and the number and order of elements must be well defined for the container assignment to be valid. The code example is the easiest way out, not the most flexible.

Comment: Have you tried with UTCDateTime fields? I received an error: Error executing code: Wrong argument types in field assignment.

Comment: In that case you will have to assign to a string variable, then do the conversion yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to care about data types conversion, just place the records to a `Map(tableID, List(Records))` and convert it with a standard `Map.xml()` method.

The good news is, that you could easily convert it back to the records just using

```
Map::createFromXML(XmlDocument::newXml(_xml).root());
```

Personally, I have created a class that makes the conversion in both directions.